# nginx: How to backup / duplicate nginx Cache-Control header?

Tags: nginx

The backend server sets the `Cache-Control` HTTP header but the frontend might manipulate it. For debugging it would be useful to see the `Cache-Control` HTTP header as the backend had set it. Hence wondering, it it possible on the backend server to set custom (`X-`) header that contains the same value as `Cache-Control`?

I tried the following already:

```
more_set_headers "X-Backend-Cache-Control: $http_cache_control";
```

But that didn't work. No header has been added.

It's not an issue with `more_set_headers`. The following worked:

```
more_set_headers "X-Backend-Cache-Control: test";
```

A header was added. But that was just a simple test to see headers can be set at all and not useful obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `$sent_http_cache_control` variable. This will contain the response's `Cache-Control` value, so:

```
more_set_headers "X-Backend-Cache-Control: $sent_http_cache_control";
```

Comment: Did you test this? Unfortunately this also does not work for me.

Comment: @adrelanos Yes. It should be applied on your front-end server, e.g. alongside `proxy_pass`.

Comment: I was setting it in the backend. That didn't work. Setting it in the frontend worked. I was hoping it's possible to set this setting in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The `$http_` variables contain HTTP headers from the HTTP request, as shown in nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_).

I don't know if there is a way to refer to HTTP response headers in nginx.